# WSO2 restrict scope by client application

Tags: wso2

I'm using WSO2 IS and API Manager and would like to restrict access token scope acquiring by client.

For instance, **client_key_1** is able to request access token only with **scope_for_client_key_1** scope and **client_key_2** is able to request access token with **scope_for_client_key_2**. But if **client_key_1** will try to request a token with **scope_for_client_key_2**, then it'll receive 403 or something like that.

Is there a way to configure it in WSO2?

Comment: Access to scopes is restricted by roles of a user. If you explain your real usecase, it'll be easier to answer this.

Comment: The real usecase is that I have multiple client applications and an API. Some API functionality depends on a specific scope of an access token. Only one client application should be allowed to use this functionality, i.e. only one client application should be able to acquire the access token with such scope. And there is no way to make the API to provide the functionality depending on something else, but the scope, as scopes are the way to pass additional authentication specific information between client application and the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 ways to achieve this. But since this is not OOTB supported by WSO2, you need to write some custom java code.

## 1) Introducing a new scope issuer with a new scope prefix.

Default role based scope issuer is [here](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/6.x/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/keymgt/issuers/RoleBasedScopesIssuer.java). You can extend it and write your own scope issuer with a new scope prefix. Within the implementation, you can check for Client key mapping as well. Then you can set the new prefix to all your scopes.

If your jar is not OSGi, add the jar to `<APIM_HOME>/repository/components/lib/` and your class will be automatically picked. If it is OSGi, add the jar to `<APIM_HOME>/repository/components/dropins/`.

## 2) Customize default scope issuer, if you don't want to use a prefix to your scopes

Customize [default class](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/6.x/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/keymgt/issuers/RoleBasedScopesIssuer.java), build the jar and patch the pack, by adding it to `<APIM_HOME>/repository/components/patches/patch0001/`.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for